# Replacing part of a char* with a smaller char*

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, string-comparison

I am having trouble understanding char* arrays and being able to replace part of one char* array, and insert a different char* array when I find a matching segment.  This is the code I am working with at the moment and I don't understand why my if check inside the for loop does not consider it to be a match.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char* sampleString = "this is a test";
    const char* oldString = "a test";
    const char* newString = "now changed";

    std::cout<< " String before amendment: " << std::endl;
    std::cout<< sampleString << std::endl;

        for (char* i = sampleString; *i; ++i)
    {
        std::cout<< i << std::endl;
        std::cout<< oldString << std::endl;

        if (i == old_str)
        {
            std::cout<<"found match"<< std::endl;
                        // replace oldString with newString
        }

    }

    std::cout<< " String after amendment: " << std::endl;
    std::cout<< sampleString << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *` arrays are simply pointers, comparing them doesn't implement a string comparison. Pick up a good introductory book on C where these things are explained.

Comment: Also, your example doesn't even compile, since `old_str` is undefined.

Comment: You'll also run into some fun if you try and modify a string literal.

Comment: Yep, an good understanding of pointers is critical to understanding C, C++, and several other languages (including Java).  You need to go back and study the basics a bit more or you'll be stumbling around in the dark.

Answer (score 4):

You're comparing the pointers, not the contents they point at.

As a couple of possibilities, you can either use `std::string` throughout, or use C-style string functions like `strncmp` to do the comparison.

Comment: ah I just forgot to dereference the Iterator and my const.  I am trying to accomplish this task without using a string class